# Расположение карточек товара с переносом на новую строку

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

встал на одной проблеме, вроде бы не такая сложная, но не могу найти вариант решения.

На странице есть карточки товара 4 карточки на 1 строке при ширине в 1600px, первая и крайняя карточки должны быть без боковых отступов. попробовал использовть display:flex и justify-content space-between. Но при добавление карточек товара (допустим в сумме будет 6 карточек(4-первая строка, 2-вторая строка)). Из-за space between карточки стоят не ровно.

[image]

```
<div className="projects">
    <h1>Проекты</h1>
    <div className="projects-container">
      <div className="card"> 
        <p>Название проекта</p>
        <span>Подробнее →</span>
      </div>
      <div className="card">
        <p>Название проекта</p>
        <span>Подробнее →</span>
      </div>
      <div className="card">
        <p>Название проекта</p>
        <span>Подробнее →</span>
      </div>
      <div className="card">
        <p>Название проекта</p>
        <span>Подробнее →</span>
      </div>

      <div className="card">
        <p>Название проекта</p>
        <span>Подробнее →</span>
      </div>

      <div className="card">
        <p>Название проекта</p>
        <span>Подробнее →</span>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <span>Все проекты →</span>

  </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.projects-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  .card {
    width: 360px;
    height: 675px;
    background-color: bisque;
    margin-top: 30px;
    p{
      color:#FFF;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    span{
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Почему у вас classname, а не class? Выложите весь код, чтобы сами карточки видны были, в том виде в котором вы выложили карточек невидно.

Comment: @Arcadiy использую React, поэтому пишу ClassName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```css
.projects-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 360px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.projects-container .card {
  width: 360px;
  height: 675px;
  background-color: bisque;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.projects-container .card p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.projects-container .card span {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects-container">
  <div class="card">
    <p>Название проекта</p>
    <span>Подробнее →</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Название проекта</p>
    <span>Подробнее →</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Название проекта</p>
    <span>Подробнее →</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Название проекта</p>
    <span>Подробнее →</span>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <p>Название проекта</p>
    <span>Подробнее →</span>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <p>Название проекта</p>
    <span>Подробнее →</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, и за готовый наглядный пример!

Comment: @shaidullin2h подвигайте экран - визуальные баги все равно есть, просто при других разрешениях экрана

Answer (score 2):

Я бы вот так сделал

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      length: 3,
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2vw;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="++length">
      Add
    </button>
  <button @click="--length">
      Remove
    </button>
  <div class="body">
    <div v-for="item in length" :key="item" class="item">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Подправил CSS вроде ровно

```
https://codepen.io/sochi-russia/pen/JjrVKME
```

```css
.projects-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: wrap;}
  .card {
    width: 360px;
    height: 675px;
    background-color: bisque;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color:#012345;
    }
    p{
      color:#FFF;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    span{
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      font-size: 18px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="projects">
    <h1>Проекты</h1>
    <div class="projects-container">
      <div class="card"> 
        <p>Название проекта</p>
        <span>Подробнее →</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>Название проекта</p>
        <span>Подробнее →</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>Название проекта</p>
        <span>Подробнее →</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <p>Название проекта</p>
        <span>Подробнее →</span>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <p>Название проекта</p>
        <span>Подробнее →</span>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <p>Название проекта</p>
        <span>Подробнее →</span>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <span>Все проекты →</span>

  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, выше мне помогли решить проблему